# Is there a way to enforce straight mouse movement(horizontal, vertical, diagonal) in macos?

Tags: keyboard, mouse

I was wondering if there is a way to enforce a straight pointer movement in macOS.

For instance when you are annotating a PDF document, you may want to make a straight stroke as an underline.

So what I'm looking for is a feature like when moving your pointers with the shift key pressed, then the pointer movement would be restricted to a straight line (either horizontal, vertical, or diagonal).

Is there such feature in macOS, or other applications which makes this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can, in fact, make specific dedicated underlines.

In the top bar, the pencil tool, there are options for Underline & strikethrough.
Both will track any text you select, letter, word or paragraph…

[image]

Giving this [the blue highlight is the selection, the red line is the added underline]

> [image]

<sup>Instructions from my beer-making xmas prezzie ;)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But I was looking for a way to restrict the mouse movement itself. The feature you suggested is provided from a lot of pdf viewer applications, but they kinda break when underlining math equations and so on.